# Next js + Custom Server + i18n useContext error

Tags: javascript, express, next.js, internationalization, i18next

Before I converted it to Custom server (Express js), I could use the i18n package without any problems. But when I converted it to Customer server, I started getting errors.

Error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
```

_app.js

```
import i18n from '@/config/i18n'
//other imports
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: any) => {
    useEffect(() => {


        let v = document.querySelector('body')
        v?.style.setProperty('--primary-color', themeConfig.primaryColor)
        v?.style.setProperty('--color-light', themeConfig.colorLight)
        v?.style.setProperty('--secondary_color', themeConfig.secondaryColor)
    }, [])


    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<>Loading</>}>
            <Head>
                <title>{pageProps?.title}</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
                <meta name="description" />
                <meta charSet="utf-8"></meta>
                <meta name="keywords" content={pageProps?.keywords}></meta>
                <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href={'/public/favicon.ico'} />
            </Head>
            
                <ConfigProvider
                    theme={antdConfig
                        < Provider store={store}>
                    <MainLayout PageLayout={Component?.PageLayout} pageProps={pageProps}>
                        <Component {...pageProps} />
                    </MainLayout>
                </>
            </ConfigProvider>
       
    </Suspense >
  )
}
export default App
```

i18n config file

```
i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    react: {
      useSuspense: false
    },
    // backend: {
    //   loadPath: '/api/translations/{{lng}}/{{ns}}',
    // },
    // resources: resources,
    lng: 'tr', // if you're using a language detector, do not define the lng option
    fallbackLng: 'tr',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // react already safes from xss => https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation#unescape
    },
  });
```

If I add i18n provider

```
 <I18nextProvider i18n = { i18n } >
...
 </I18nextProvider>
```

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')
```

(It was added in provider before I converted it to custom server)
I could not find the solution to the problem anywhere, I have been searching for 2 days.